# Организация структуры проекта Django

Tags: python, django

Пишу сайт для прохождения тестов.
Структура пректа изображена на фото

[image: Структура проекта]

Для работы сайта мне нужно где-то хранить описания результатов теста. Предполагаю, что они будут храниться в файле static/testapp/test_data/test_data.py Данные будут храниться в константах - словарях. Насколько это правильное решение?

Так же по результатам теста хочу создавать pdf файл, который пользователь сможет загрузить.
Где правильно с точки зрения организации проекта, писать функцию по созданию этого файла? В testapp/views.py или может быть создать какой-то менеджер (например testapp/manadger.py) для создания таких файлов?

Comment: static используется для связки html+css+js, при деплое используется команда `collectstatic`, которая и собирает все эти данные в одну папку из сущностей `static`. Не думаю, что это хорошая идея хранить там питоновские данные. А по второй части: почему бы не создать еще одно приложение, которое будет являться сервисным и в нем определить всю рутину с документацией. Или если это совсем одно функция, то определить ее в `views.py`

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо!